# VLC is dropping frames/stuttering when trying to play 1080p@60FPS video on rMBP w. 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7

Tags: video, performance, quicktime, vlc, h.264

When I try to play a video with 1920x1080 pixels and 60fps, in H.264 format using VLC player. It cannot keep up with this work and frequently drops frames (in other words, it's not playing it "smoothly").

OS X's QuickTime player seems to be free from this problem, but it's not a solution, since it's limited to a small subset of formats (can't handle 10-bit or 4:2:2 colorspaces, or MKV container, etc.)

Is there a way to fix that problem (without upgrading to macOS Sierra), or I should look for another video player if VLC's performance is not good enough?

The computer is a Retina MacBook Pro with a 2.3 GHz i7 processor and a NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB dedicated GPU, and OS X version is 10.11.6. I'm not sure how to check if secondary GPU is being really used for heavy lifting instead of Intel one when playing videos.

VLC says it's up to date:

> VLC 2.2.4 is currently the newest version available

Comment: Are you using the latest release of VLC? You should edit your question to include this information.

Comment: @IconDaemon done!

Comment: What's the video's bitrate? Is it a super-compressed 10Mbps, DSLR 40Mbps, or higher?

Comment: @NoahL it likely doesn't matter, I tested with 36Mbps from camera and also 20Mbps recompressed, VLC struggles to play both.

Comment: I was wondering if it was a read/write problem because I've played 40+Mbps 1080p60 videos without a problem using VLC on a MBPr with integrated graphics. I assume (but am just checking) that you know that the original video isn't jerky (check it in QT?), it's just the VLC playback?

Comment: @NoahL yes, QT plays it normally. Also VLC uses 100% CPU.

Comment: Wow! I've played back stuff encoded at h.265 and it's never boosted CPU that high. Is it like that for just one video or do you have the problem on multiple? If it's on multiple, I'd suggest doing a complete uninstall of VLC, caches and library folders included (instructions are likely available online), then redownloading and installing VLC player. If it's only one video, try reencoding it (either with VLC or with Handbrake or similar). You might also want to try encoding it as an h.265 hevc file and see how that works.

Comment: @NoahL It's with all videos which are 1080p/60fps. I will try reinstalling VLC when I come home again. Not sure if I will try h.265, it takes forever to encode on my laptop…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem by switching to [MPV](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv) for playing videos, which is also superior to VLC in many other ways.